# django-rest-framework, third-party javascript app registration and creating new thread

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I have created a forum project something similar to these with Forum model,Category model, thread model, comment model, user model, Notification model. I exposed these model through rest-framework with ForumSerializer, CategorySerializer and such. In api viewsets I have viewsets similar to this:

```
class CategoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
```

It works .yay!

I worked on to make it something similar to what disqus offers. A 3rd party comments hosting site. I worked with third party javascript and created a javascript snippet that can be embeded on other sites. I installed django-cors-headers and enabled Cross-origin resource sharing.

Here comes my question. If a user registers a website and uses javascript snippet, I need to create a new thread using the headline and other unique identifiers. I figured how disqus does this. (Q1) What is/are the best practices to do this type of registration. Providing a api key(secret and public) or any other?

```
f ----->forum,
t_i----> identifier,
t_u----> url 
t_s----> slug,
t_e----> title,
t_d----> documentTitle,
t_t----> title || documentTitle,
t_c ---->category,
s_o----> sortOrder,
l----> language
```

Disqus creates a new thread and serves the comment section at something like this, which is embeded in an iframe

Example url:

```
https://example.com/embed/comments/?base=default&
version=edb619270a92c3035c453faa7c9444d1&
f=example&
t_i=article_2431522&
t_u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fhollywood%2Flatest-trailer-of-spectre-is-out-james-bond-is-back-all-guns-and-cars-blazing-2431522.html%09&
t_e=Latest%20trailer%20of%20%27Spectre%27%20is%20out%3A%20James%20Bond%20is%20back%20all%20guns%20and%20cars%20blazing&
t_d=Latest%20trailer%20of%20%27Spectre%27%20is%20out%3A%20James%20Bond%20is%20back%20all%20guns%20and%20cars%20blazing&
t_t=Latest%20trailer%20of%20%27Spectre%27%20is%20out%3A%20James%20Bond%20is%20back%20all%20guns%20and%20cars%20blazing&
s_o=default
```

(Q2) How to create a new thread and save the above unique identifiers, if it's not already created in django to serve.

Is there any open source or other project I can see to get some reference on how to do it.

I am looking for best practices.

P.S. I do not require code,I would appreciate if provided though. Explained it technical terms with logical steps will do. I'll search.

P.P.S I searched all over github for any open-source projects to see how they implement. Searched 790+ projects with no hits so far.

Thank you very much